# When add include netfilter.h i got error that fields 'in','in6' has incomplete type

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

Have simple , empty project without any code. just includes.
The include linux/netfilter.h cause to compilation error:

```
In file included from ../src/main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/linux/netfilter.h:65:17: error: field ‘in’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/linux/netfilter.h:66:18: error: field ‘in6’ has incomplete type
```

As you can see in the simple project i have 2 includes if i remove the iostream include i will get additional error - '/usr/include/linux/sysctl.h:40:2: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>

int main() {
}
```

if i add include of netinet/in.h before netfilter.h than no errors.

why my simple main program cannot has these compilation errors?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
union nf_inet_addr {
    __u32       all[4];
    __be32      ip;
    __be32      ip6[4];
    struct in_addr  in;
    struct in6_addr in6;
};
```

`struct in_addr` and `in6_addr` are not complete types. so, you should include header with declaration of structures before `netfilter.h`

Comment: Why dont them include the types? why include for one thing is not complete?

Answer (score 5):

Try including `netinet/in.h` before `linux/netfilter.h`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
```