# invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’ - kernel module compilation error

Tags: linux, module, compilation, kernel

I have a kernel module which i am able to compile successfully against native running kernel header (4.4.0-21-generic).

Here is the Makefile:

```
vm@vm:~/Documents/kernelDev/Netfilter/skbuff_analyser$ cat Makefile
obj-m += sk_buff.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Now, i want to compile the same kernel module against another kernel version 4.5.3. I modify the Makefile as follows :

```
vm@vm:~/Documents/kernelDev/Netfilter/skbuff_analyser$ cat Makefile
obj-m += sk_buff.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/4.5.3/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/4.5.3/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But, now it is not picking up the headers for 4.5.3 and compilation terminated.

Here is the content of `/lib/modules`

```
vm@vm:/lib/modules$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 May 10 17:59 4.4.0-21-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 10 20:09 4.5.3
```

And,

I check the contents of `/lib/modules/4.5.3/build` is equivalent to that of `/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build`

```
vm@vm:/lib/modules/4.5.3/build$ pwd
/lib/modules/4.5.3/build
vm@vm:/lib/modules/4.5.3/build$ ls
arch     crypto                 firmware  Kbuild   MAINTAINERS          Module.symvers  scripts     usr
block    Documentation          fs        Kconfig  Makefile         net                 security    virt
certs    drivers                include   kernel   mm               README          sound       vmlinux
COPYING  Fedora21-x86-root_fs   init      lib      modules.builtin  REPORTING-BUGS  System.map  vmlinux.o
CREDITS  Fedora21-x86-root_fs2  ipc       linux    modules.order    samples         tools
```

`update`

I see that, only the structures and datatypes defined in `linux/netfilter.h` are not being picked up when compiling against new kernel version. If i declare the structure in my c file explicitly, then error goes away. NO Idea whats the problem with this header file.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <uapi/linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h> // for mac header
#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/inetdevice.h> //  for inet_select_addr()
#include <linux/if.h>

/home/vm/Documents/kernelDev/Netfilter/skbuff_analyser/sk_buff.c:514:2:     error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct nf_hook_ops’
netfilter_ops_post_routing.priv    =  NULL;
```

Comment: Have you clean build files in `~/Documents/kernelDev/Netfilter/skbuff_analyser` before switching to another kernel? What **exact error message** is?

Comment: it is not picking any data structure defined in <linux/netfilter.h>

Comment: /home/vm/Documents/kernelDev/Netfilter/skbuff_analyser/sk_buff.c:553:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘nf_unregister_hook’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  nf_unregister_hook(&netfilter_ops_pre_routing); /*unregister NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING hook*/

Comment: looks like same problem is being faced here.

`http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/trouble-compiling-linux-module-291002/`
and here
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665529/when-add-include-netfilter-h-i-got-error-that-fields-in-in6-has-incomplete-t`

Comment: According to content of header `linux/netfiler.h`, kernel `4.4.0-21-generic` against which you are failed to build probably doesn't configured to use netfiler: the option *CONFIG_NETFILER* is disabled for it. Check that option.

Comment: i do not have config file against which i compiler my kernel, is there any other way to check if this flag was enabled ?

Comment: yes, in .config file i see this flag is not set. Will recompile kernel again with this flag set and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that i built my kernel in which CONFIG_NETFILER flag in .config file was not set, hence kernel did not have NETFILTER support though netfilter.h existed.

I rebuilt the kernel with this flag set and able to compile the netfilter module.